# List the last two records for each id

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Afternoon!

I'm having trouble list the last two records each idmicro

Ex:

```
idhist  idmicro idother     room     unit              Dtmov
100     1102        0         8      coa       2009-10-23 10:40:00.000
101     1102        0         1      coa       2009-10-28 10:40:00.000
102     1102        0         2       dib       2008-10-24 10:40:00.000
103     1201        0         6      diraf     2008-10-23 10:40:00.000
104     1201        0         7      diraf     2009-10-21 10:40:00.000
105     1201        0         4     dimel     2008-10-22 10:40:00.000
```

Would look like this:

ex:

result

```
idhist  idmicro idoutros    room      unit               Dtmov
101     1102        0         1       coa      2009-10-28 10:40:00.000
102     1102        0         2       dib      2008-10-24 10:40:00.000
103     1201        0         6      diraf     2008-10-22 10:40:00.000
104     1201        0         7      diraf     2009-10-21 10:40:00.000
```

I'm starting to delve into SQL and am having trouble finding this solution

Sorry

Thank you.

EDIT: I am using SQL server, and I made no query. 
Yes! is based on the date and time

Comment: Which `RDBMS` are you using? Also, can you show your unsuccessful attempt?

Comment: when you say "last" is it based on datetime? or which criteria?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add the query you are using, the output you are receiving, and the output that you desire? The way it is right now we don't know if the result is what you want or if it is what you don't want.

Comment: Sorry. I made the corrections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same thing with an imbricated `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY idmicro ORDER BY idhist
            ) AS ind
        ,*
    FROM data
    ) AS initialResultSet
WHERE initialResultSet.ind < 3
```

Here is a sample [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3e79/5) with how this query works.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH etc
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY idmicro ORDER BY idhist
            ) AS r
        ,count() OVER (
            PARTITION BY idmicro ORDER BY idhist
            ) cfrom TABLE
    )
SELECT *
FROM etc
WHERE r > c - 2
```

Comment: The following error occurred:The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.???

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number and over partition

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY idmicro ORDER BY idhist desc) AS rownum
    FROM data
    ) AS initialResultSet
WHERE initialResultSet.rownum<=2
```